# Cannot read property of undefined and checks always throw errors

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use the oberserver pattern to listen for a variable. At first the incoming object is undefined. If this is the case, further functions should not be executed. Only if the object is not undefined, the functions should be executed. I have tried many things like `if(a !== undefined)`, `if(typeof a != 'undefined')`, ... I always get the same error in the line `a.prop.find()` or in the if statement itself.

> Cannot read property 'a' of undefined

How can I check correctly?

**A.class**

```
const a = state.find(state => state.id === this.id);
return a;
```

**B.class**

```
this.val.subscribe((a) => {
  // Check if a is undefined
  a.prop.find(...);
}
```

Comment: in `A.class` this line `state.find(state => state.id === this.id)` is probably returning undefined, so when it gets to `b.class` your looking at undefined.

Comment: in your subscribe callback please put an example of how you are writing your if statement (including the body of the statement).

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an error like:

```
Cannot read property 'a' of undefined
```

That means, you're trying to access the property `a` of an `undefined` object.

What you're doing here is checking if `a` is undefined. But what you should be doing is checking if the object, from which you're trying to access the property `a`, is `undefined`.

From the code you've posted, it doesn't seem the error is present there. Look where ever you're trying to access the property `a` and you'll find the root cause.

For example:

```js
// An undefined object
let obj = undefined;

// Now if you try to access any property of `obj`
obj.a;
```

This will throw:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined
```